# How to include a chef recipe based on the output from bash command?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to get the count of a particular process , and include the config recipe only if there are no processes.

Something to this effect.  How is this possible in chef?

```
if !( "(ps aux | grep splunkd | grep -v grep | wc -l) > 0 ") 
  include_recipe 'platform::splunk_config' 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can offer an idea to use [`ruby_block` resourece](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) in a conjunction with a [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html), and it should be something like:

```
ruby_block 'splank configuration' do
  block { include_recipe 'platform::splunk_config' }
  not_if "ps aux | grep splunkd | grep -v grep | wc -l > 0"
end
```

but i haven't tried it :)